# Is there a way to remove a GraphicsLayer from the map? - ArcGIS JS API 3.27

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am attempting to remove a GraphicsLayer that was added into the map. This GraphicsLayer was added with `var resultsGraphics = new GraphicsLayer({ id: 'resultsGraphics' });` after a map tool is opened, and needs to be removed when the tool is closed. I have tried `map.removeLayer('resultsGraphics')` which doesn't work, and baffles me that it doesn't because `map.getLayer('resultsGraphics')` works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map.removeLayer()` function [takes a *layer object* as an input parameter](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/map-amd.html#removelayer). So you need to do something like this:

```
map.removeLayer(resultsGraphics); // passing the variable
```

Or if you'd like to use the layer ID:

```
map.removeLayer(map.getLayer('resultsGraphics'));
```

Comment: Didn't think about that because I thought `map.removeLayer()`'s only parameter was the layer's ID.

Comment: Would just `map.removeLayer(resultsGraphics)` have worked (using the variable instead of the name in quotes)?

Comment: Great point @kenbuja ! Added that option. Thanks